# can modify incoming call window for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4

I have an app that store some data such as telephone numbers, contact name and other extra data in a sqlite database, it is possible when i receive a call intercept that event and search in the database if that phone number is there? if i find the phone number in the database show some extra data in the incoming window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible without jailbreaking. And even with, probably a very bad idea.